# big size after compiling a c++ code

Tags: c++

My IDE is Code::Blocks

I wrote a simple c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
   cout << "hello, World!";
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc 7.1` with c++14 support

when I choose Debug mode & build&run the app it produces :

```
Output file is bin\Debug\learn.exe with size 13.56 MB
```

**Note :** size is 13.56 MB

after that, I chose Release Mode then I built & ran the app, it gave me this :

```
Output file is bin\Release\learn.exe with size 1.12 MB
```

Now the **Output** is 1.12 MB

I am confused if there was a data loss or something like that, maybe libraries .... ?

Is it normal?

Comment: Debug builds contain a lot of information in them so they can be debugged.  Most likely that is what you are seeing.

Comment: Normal.  There are one or more tools available to 'strip' the debug info from the big file, which would create the smaller file.  One such tool might be 'strip'.  see man strip.  It is not the tool I remember, but it showed up first in today's search.

Comment: Easily discovered by simply Googling `debug builds large`. Is something broken in your search engine, or did you not use it?

Comment: I agree with @NathanOliver, cuz debugging process needs a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of debug builds is that the executable incorporates things that you can, y'know, debug with. That includes information that would usually not be kept, like the names of variables.

The code is also less terse because it has not been optimised as much (optimisations being unhelpful to the debugging process).

You can definitely expect debug builds to be larger.

Comment: what u mean with "information that would usually not be kept (variables names)" ?, why they won't be kept by the compiler ?

Comment: @AdelBenhamida: Why would they be? It might be time for you to perform some more research on the compilation process, why we do it, and what the end result looks like. The computer has no knowledge of or need for variable names — those are just a fiction for the human reader.

Comment: You just gave me an information that i didn't know about the compilation process, Thank you so much :)